# How to remove string that is no longer needed in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, string

This seemed like it should be very simple to do yet I've not been able to find an answer after weeks of looking.

I'm trying to remove strings that are no longer needed. Regex_replace sounds perfect but is not available in MySQL.

In MySQL how would I accomplish changing this:

[quote=ABC;xxxxxx]

to this:
[quote=ABC]

The issues are:
- this can appear anywhere in a text blob
- the xxxxxx can only be numeric but may be 6, 7 or 8 characters long
- not adding/removing any rows, just rewriting the contents of one column on one row at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need REGEX_Replace (though it would make things easier of course).

Assuming that the example you presented is a real reflection of what you have:

1. Your starting point is with the string `[quote=<something>;`, meaning that you can start searching for `[quote=`,
2. Once you found it, you need to search for `;` and after that for `]`,
3. Once you found them both, you know what to extract when where to start for the next search (if the pattern you mentioned can appear more than once within a singe blob.

Did I get you correctly?

**EDIT**

This paradigm is aimed to convert all instances of `[quote=ABC;xxxxxx]` to `[quote=ABC]` under the following assumptions:

1. The pattern can appear any number of times within the input string,
2. The length of `xxxxxx` is not fixed,
3. The resulting string (after removing all the appearances of `;xxxxxx`) should replace the value in the table,
4. Performance is not an issue since either this is going to be a one-time job (through the whole table) or it will run every time on a single string (e.g. before INSERTing a new record).

Some MySQL functions that will be used:

1. `INSTR`: Searches within a string for the first appearance of a sub-string and returns the position (offset) where the sub-string was found,
2. `SUBSTR`: Returns a substring from a string (several ways to use it),
3. `CONCAT`: Concatenates two or more strings.

The guidelines presented here apply for the manipulation of a single INPUT string. If this needs to be used over, say, a whole table, simply get the strings into a CURSOR and loop.

Here are the steps:

1. Declare five INT local variables to serve as indices and total input string length, say L_Start, L_UpTo, l_Total_Length, l_temp1 and l_temp 2, setting the initial value for l_Start = 1 and l_Total_Length = LENGTH(INPUT_String),
2. Declare a string variable into which you will copy the "cleaned" result and initiate it as `''`, say l_Output_str; also declare a temporary string to hold the value of `'ABD'`, say l_Quote,
3. Start a infinite loop (you will set the exit condition within it; see below),
4. Exit loop if l_Start >= l_Total_Length (here is one of the two exit points from the loop),
5. Find the first location of `'[quote='` within the input string starting from L_Start,
6. If the returned value is 0 (i.e. substring not found), concatenate the current contents of l_Output_str with whatever remains if the input string from position L_start (e.g. `SET l_Output_str = CONCAT(l_Output_str,SUBSTR(INPUT_String,L_Start) ;`) and exit loop (second exit position),
7. Search the input string for the `;` symbol starting from L_start + 7 (i.e. the length of `[quote=`) and save the value in l_temp_1,
8. Search the input string for the `]` symbol starting from L_start + 7 + l_temp2 and save the value in l_temp_2,
9. Add the found result to output string as `SET l_Output_str = CONCAT(l_Output_str,'[quote=',SUBSTR(INPUT_String,L_Start + 7, l_temp_2 - l_temp_1),']') ;`,
10. Set L_Start = L_Start + 7 + l_temp_2 + 1 ;
11. End of loop.

Notes:

1. As I neither made the code nor tested it, it is possible that I'm not setting indices correctly; you will need to perform detailed tests to make get it working as needed;
2. The above **IS** the method I suggested;
3. If the input string is very long (many MBs), you might observe poor performance (i.e. it might take few seconds to complete) because of the concatenations. There are some steps that can be taken to improve performance, but let's have this working first and then, if needed, tackle the performance issues.

Hope that the above is clear and comprehensive.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do - I want to match a string and remove it. I know the start to match - I know the end.  The string will be different, but it will always be 6, 7 or 8 characters long - it will always start with [quote= and it will always end with the next ] in the blob.

Comment: So, you have in my answer above the paradigm to implement it. Give it a try and post if you encounter difficulties.

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear, I'm looking for help with "paradigm" and "implementing" it :-)  I'm very adept at basic REPLACE and UPDATE and SELECT SQL but am having great trouble putting together a basic select/replace/update defining and using strings. I've been searching this site and others for a somewhat generic select/replace/update defining a string by what precedes and follows it so I can use that as a frame to adjust as needed.  I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Well... SO is **NOT** aimed to have people around the world creating code for you, but it is more aimed to have them examine your code and helping you to understand why it does not work. I will not write the code for you, but will add to my answer a more detailed description of what you need to code. Stay tuned as this addition will be within the coming 24 hours.

Comment: Detailed paradigm posted.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you. I should be able to put it together from that.